# sql 2008 point reprojection

Tags: sql-server-2008, mapping, coordinates, coordinate-systems

i have a table with two fields (X,Y)
they hold the location of points in New Israel Projection (EPSG: 2039) (e.g. X=194545.05941493041, Y=668112.83849507652)
i want to reproject all points to WGS84 (EPSG: 4326). (e.g. the same coordinates above should translate to something around: 34.940578289586, 32.106153057749005

how do i do that in SQL 2008?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a easier solution now, but what I had to do a few years ago was the following:
I needed to reproject between UTM33N(x, y ) and WGS84 (lat lon).

I use http://projnet.codeplex.com/ to translate each coordinate. The key you need is the two WKT (WellKnownText) that make up the projection model.
For me it was some hours of try and fail, but eventually I had a good translation.

Later when we started to use spatial indexes I created a SSIS package to reproject all data on inport.

There may be better solutions that that today:
perhaps it's supported by http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/
Also I see that many are using ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: thanks for the links i will have a look at them. i was thinking more in the lines of using sql server's built in functionality as i think it does support projections

Comment: @dani-avni I'm very interested if you find any support for reprojections between different coordinate systems built in sql server. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/is-it-possible-to-reproject-spatial-data-using-sql-server 
I't may be supported in sqlspatialtools which are SQL CLR functions that extend the spatial support.